# Google Apps Script sendEmail: multiple recipients string?

Tags: google-apps-script

Using sendEmail, how can I send an email to multiple comma-separated recipients by combining two form fields? It seems to work when (lastrow,4) has only one value (abc@domain.com) but not for more than one (abc@domain.com, xyz@domain.com). Current code is below, and the variable in question is **recipientsTo**.

```
function FormEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetform = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Name of the sheet which contains the results
  var lastrow = sheetform.getLastRow();
  var recipientsTO = sheetform.getRange(lastrow,3).getValue() + "@domain.com";
  var recipientsCC = ""
  var team = sheetform.getRange(lastrow,5).getValue();
  var datestamp = Utilities.formatDate(sheetform.getRange(lastrow,1).getValue(), "GMT - 5", "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var html = "Intro text;

  //The questions order in the email will be the order of the column in the sheet  
    for (var i = 2; i < 11; ++i) {
    html = html + "<b>" + sheetform.getRange(1,i).getValue() + "</b><br>";
    html = html + sheetform.getRange(lastrow,i).getValue() + "</p><br>";
       }

  //Add additional emails if entered in form field
  if (sheetform.getRange(lastrow,4).getValue() !== "") {
    recipientsTO = recipientsTO + "," + sheetform.getRange(lastrow,4).getValue()
  }

  //CC if response to a question is "Yes"
  if (sheetform.getRange(lastrow,10).getValue() == "Yes") {
    recipientsCC = "ccEmaIL@gmail.com"
  }


  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipientsTO,
    cc: recipientsCC,
    subject: "Subject",
    htmlBody: html,
});


}
```

Comment: You might try adding Logger.log(recipientsTO) just below the if statement that adds the additional email addresses and then viewing the log to see if you can see any malformed addesses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the sendEmail(message) documentation, the TO field only has one recipient.
Whereas the CC field can have multiple recipients separated by comma.

http://goo.gl/CGjiJ

`to - String - the address of the recipient.

cc -String - a comma separated list of email addresses to CC`

Another option would be to use sendEmail(String,String,String,Object) in that function "recipient   String  the addresses of the recipients, separated by commas".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. You may be right, but I'm confused by that documentation page: [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app). Under sendEmail(message) it says that "to" is "the address of the recipient" and under sendEmail(to, replyTo, subject, body) it says that "to" is "the addresses of the recipients, separated by commas." Not sure which to believe. At any rate, it works when the appended cell value is one recipient (total of 2 in "to:) but not if it's two (total of 3 in "to"), leading me to believe that it's just bad syntax...

Comment: "Which to believe" - each function receives seperate parameters, believe both. Can you debug and display the value of "to" field with one, two or three recipients? If it is bad syntax, then debugging it should show it. Try without any spaces between the comma and the third email.

Comment: ::facepalm:: My original code above works fine, so feel free to use it.

Thanks so much to mitrube for your help. I wasn't familiar with the debugger, but tried it, and everything is working fine, with or without spaces! The error report I got was referring to a malformed email address in (lastrow, 3). I did learn a few things through the experience though.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code from my production script:

```
//check quota and log
const emailsLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
console.log( emailsLeft + " emails left in quota");

//get list of emails from spreadsheet itself
//filter out empty rows
const emails = getTab("Config").getRange("D2:D").getValues().map(function(el){ return el[0]; }).filter(function(el){ return el != '' });  

//send emails from NO_REPLY email, subject and HTML body
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: emails.join(","),
  subject: subject,
  htmlBody: html,
  noReply: true
});

function getTab(name) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  return sheet.getSheetByName(name);
}
```

getTab() and other helper functions can be found here
https://github.com/tim-kozak/google-spreadsheet-helpers